# I have really scratched my head with fire by asking the question!

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

> **It  is  like  scratching  one's  head  with  fire**
>
> **I have really  scratched  my head with fire by asking this question**
>
> **I  have  really  put  my foot  in it  by  asking  the  question**

If  somebody  has  invited  trouble  by  doing  some  thing  unknowingly or  innocently,This  proverb is  being  used  in  Indian languages..This  is  not  eqjual  to  play  with fire or  refers  to  self defeating  person    or  action.

You are  playing  with  fire  means that  **you are   doing
a  dangerous  thing** .  But  the  proverb does  not  mean  that  it  is  dangerous.It  means   **a  foolish  decision taken  unknowingly or unwittingly which  causes  one  some  trouble**. The  proverb  is  used  after  a  decision  taken  has  turned  out  to be  somewhat  troublesome  but not  dangerous  for  the  person .

What  is  the  equal idiom  in  English?

I believe that  Put  one's foot  in  it  is almost equal to  the  idiom I  have  questioned because  most  of  the  native  English  speakers  misunderstood  that  fire connotes  a dangerous   situation.In fact, the  proverb  is  used  in  a  situation  like  mine.I  am  not  in  a great  danger  but  getting  downvotes.So  I  have  used  the  expression  to  show  that  it  can be used  in  a humorous  context  too.

Comment: Unless you can better explain _why_ the equivalent _is_ not  'playing with fire' – doing something exciting maybe that could well end in disaster – this is merely general reference. There need be no 'playing' involved in the dangerous course of action.

Comment: "Walking into a lion's den" can involve entering the den despite knowing full well that a lion lives there, or it can involve wandering into it by accident. In the former situation, the action is rash and foolhardy; in the latter, the action is merely ignorant and unwitting, which may make it a match for the expression you have in mind.

Comment: I think  I have  really scratched  my  head with  fire  by asking  this  question

Comment: Because the expression that you are trying to match evidently doesn't carry the element of danger that "play with fire" does, I don't think the two expressions are at all equivalent. I'm not sure what the downvoters are objecting to here, but perhaps they are reacting to Edwin Ashworth's comment that you needed to explain why the two fire phrases aren't interchangeable. You've done that now, it seems to me, and I hope that at least some of the downvoters will consider rescinding their downvotes in light of that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that avoids the serious danger/harm implied by such expressions as "walked into the lion's den," "put [one's] head into a noose," and "cut off [one's] nose to spite [one's] face" is the more pedestrian—literally and figuratively—expression "put [one's] foot in it." Here is the entry for this expression in Christine Ammer, [*The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA365&dq=%22put+one%27s+foot+in+it+Make+a+blunder%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV9rGfyc7lAhXnJzQIHS9ZB58Q6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22put%20one's%20foot%20in%20it%20Make%20a%20blunder%22&f=false), second edition):

> **put one's foot in it** Make a blunder, as in *I didn't know it was a surprise party; I guess I put my foot in it*. This expression presumably alludes to setting one' foot down in mud or excrement. {Late 1700s}

The blunder in Ammer's example is unexplained, but it probably involved the speaker's ruining the surprise of the surprise party by giving it away to the guest of honor. The trouble that the speaker incurs as a result of this misstep is simply that the planners of the surprise party may be annoyed at the speaker for the untimely revelation.

The expression "put [one's] foot in it" is used for just such instances of faux pas as this one. No one suffers serious injury or other damage, but the person who has acted incautiously, indiscreetly, or insensitively is left with the social equivalent of a very messy shoe as a result. The related phrase, "put [one's] foot in [one's] mouth" is more narrowly concerned with errors in speech (or by extension, writing), so it would work in Ammer's example above but not in a case where the blunder was nonverbal. For example: *The pie was delicious, but I didn't realize that my spouse had been planning to bring it to a book club meeting tonight. I really put my foot in it this time.*

Comment: @ Sven YargsI have  really  found  the  correct  and  almost  idiom in English.I have  changed  my  opinion  and accepted  your  answer  and  upvoted it  too. I really  put  my  foot  in it  by  asking  the question

Comment: @Englishmonger: The problem for most native English speakers (including me) who encountered this Indian idiom for the first time in your question is that it is hard for us to see beyond the real-world fact that "scratching one's head with fire" would be extremely dangerous (and painful). To get to a suitable idiomatic match in English, we need to look beyond the literal sense of the Indian expression and understand its idiomatic meaning, which you have now provided.

Answer (score 1):

"I cannot think of a direct equivalent, but "[Putting your head in the noose](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+your+head+in+a+noose)", is possibly close.

This refers metaphorically to someone voluntarily placing their head in the hangman's noose, and allowing themselves to be killed (hung).  That is, bad things happening as a result of their own actions.

Possibly: [ADD INSULT TO INJURY](https://onlineteachersuk.com/english-idioms/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a direct correlation, but there are warnings not to let it happen:
1) Look before you leap.
2) Be careful what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

["Stirring up a hornet's nest"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stir+up+a+hornet%27s+nest) sounds similar to what you're looking for.